# BarChart: plotting bars at given positions

Tags: charts

Is there a way to get `BarChart` to position any number of bars of arbitrary widths at arbitrary positions? e.g. I want to plot normal vertically-standing bars, with bar number one spanning from 1 to 3 of the horizontal axis, and bar number two spanning from 2 to 5, and so on.

Comment: Look at `Histogram` and its bin width specification *`bspec`*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** You can also use a custom `ChartElementFunction` and pass the rectangle starting positions as metadata:

```
ceF[ced_ : "Rectangle"] := 
   ChartElementData[ced][{{#3[[1]], #3[[1]] + (#[[1, 2]] - #[[1, 1]])}, #[[2]]}, ##2] &
```

**Examples:**

```
data = {{2, 1}, {3, 4}};
positions = {1, 2};
ticks = Range[positions[[-1]] + data[[-1, -1]]];

RectangleChart[Thread[data -> positions], 
  ChartStyle -> 97, ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[.6],
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {ticks, Automatic}}, 
  ChartElementFunction -> ceF[]]
```

[image]

With `positions = {2, 7}` and `ChartElementFunction -> ceF["GlassRectangle"]` we get

[image]

```
SeedRandom[77]
data = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {5, 2}];
positions = Sort @ RandomSample[Range @ 20, 5];
ticks = Range[positions[[-1]] + data[[-1, -1]]];

RectangleChart[Thread[data -> positions], 
 ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[.6],
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {ticks, Automatic}},
 ChartElementFunction -> ceF["FadingRectangle"]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use [`RectangleChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RectangleChart.html) with the option setting `BarSpacing->-1`:

```
opts1 = {BarSpacing -> -1, ChartStyle -> {Opacity[.5, Red], Opacity[.5, Green]}};

rc1 = RectangleChart[{{2, 1}, {3, 4}}, opts1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To add the ticks to the horizontal axis:

```
opts2 = Join[opts1, {Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{#, # + 1} & /@ Range[-1, 5], Automatic, None, None},
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 4}, {0, 4}}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}}];

rc2 = RectangleChart[{{2, 1}, {3, 4}}, opts2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Post-process if you wish to remove the extra lines and ticks below the bars:

```
rc2 /. Line[__] :> {}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for this answer, which indeed produces the example I gave. I've updated the question to emphasise that I seek arbitrary widths and spacings. I think I may just need to use Graphics with Rectangle.

Comment: @CarbonFlambe, does the updated version answer your question?

Comment: Yes indeed -- thanks!